# How to repeat a standardization on multiple columns with different values in R?

Tags: r, automation

**The task**
Back in the days I was working on just a few variables - usually 5 - 10, and perhaps one or two split-variables. Now the amount of variables are increasing rapidly and they are changing names. For example, I have this (dummy) dataset:

```
   V_1 V_2 V_3 V_4 V_5
1    x   3   3   2   3
2    x   4   4   3   3 
3    x   2   5   4   4
4    x   5   4   5   4
5    t   6   2   4   5
6    t   4   3   5   4
7    t   5   4   4   5
8    t   3   5   6   4
9    s   4   6   2   4
10   s   2   5   4   4
11   s   3   4   3   6
12   s   4   5   4   2
13   r   3   4   5   2
14   r   2   3   4   4
15   r   3   4   4   5
16   r   4   3   4   4
```

where V_1 is the split-variable, and I use:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data %>%
  group_by(V_1) %>%
  mutate(S_v2=scale(V_2)*2+5.5)
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(V_1) %>%
  mutate(S_v3=scale(V_3)*2+5.5)
df3 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(V_1) %>%
  mutate(S_v4=scale(V_4)*2+5.5)
df4 <- df3 %>%
  group_by(V_1) %>%
  mutate(S_v5=scale(V_5)*2+5.5)
```

And the result will be this:

```
 V_1     V_2   V_3   V_4   V_5 S_v2[,1] S_v3[,1] S_v4[,1] S_v5[,1]
   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 x         3     3     2     3     4.73     3.05     3.18     3.77
 2 x         4     4     3     3     6.27     5.5      4.73     3.77
 3 x         2     5     4     4     3.18     7.95     6.27     7.23
 4 x         5     4     5     4     7.82     5.5      7.82     7.23
 5 t         6     2     4     5     7.82     3.18     3.93     7.23
 6 t         4     3     5     4     4.73     4.73     6.02     3.77
 7 t         5     4     4     5     6.27     6.27     3.93     7.23
 8 t         3     5     6     4     3.18     7.82     8.11     3.77
 9 s         4     6     2     4     7.07     7.95     2.89     5.5 
10 s         2     5     4     4     2.89     5.5      7.07     5.5 
11 s         3     4     3     6     4.98     3.05     4.98     7.95
12 s         4     5     4     2     7.07     5.5      7.07     3.05
13 r         3     4     5     2     5.5      7.23     8.5      2.72
14 r         2     3     4     4     3.05     3.77     4.5      5.90
15 r         3     4     4     5     5.5      7.23     4.5      7.49
16 r         4     3     4     4     7.95     3.77     4.5      5.90
```

This is to standardize each of the variables on a 10-point scale by the split-variable. So far so good (if you have just got a few variables...). Now, I have 300+ variables, and the variable names from various datasets are constantly changing, making this task pretty tedious if I'm to follow my old routine.

I have looked at various loop-functions but haven't manage to get things right. The dataset is growing and my boss gets impatient. The ultimate goal is to work with a code that can automate these things. Can anyone help me out?

**This is what I need:**

```
df <- data %>%
  group_by(colname_1) %>%
  mutate(S_colname = scale(colname)*2+5.5)
Repeat this block of code with the same group_by but with different 
colnames
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `across`:

```r
data %>%
  group_by(V_1) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ c(scale(.)) * 2 + 5.5, .names = "S_{.col}")) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 16 × 9
#    V_1     V_2   V_3   V_4   V_5 S_V_2 S_V_3 S_V_4 S_V_5
#    <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 x         3     3     2     3  4.73  3.05  3.18  3.77
#  2 x         4     4     3     3  6.27  5.5   4.73  3.77
#  3 x         2     5     4     4  3.18  7.95  6.27  7.23
#  4 x         5     4     5     4  7.82  5.5   7.82  7.23
#  5 t         6     2     4     5  7.82  3.18  3.93  7.23
#  6 t         4     3     5     4  4.73  4.73  6.02  3.77
#  7 t         5     4     4     5  6.27  6.27  3.93  7.23
#  8 t         3     5     6     4  3.18  7.82  8.11  3.77
#  9 s         4     6     2     4  7.07  7.95  2.89  5.5 
# 10 s         2     5     4     4  2.89  5.5   7.07  5.5 
# 11 s         3     4     3     6  4.98  3.05  4.98  7.95
# 12 s         4     5     4     2  7.07  5.5   7.07  3.05
# 13 r         3     4     5     2  5.5   7.23  8.5   2.72
# 14 r         2     3     4     4  3.05  3.77  4.5   5.90
# 15 r         3     4     4     5  5.5   7.23  4.5   7.49
# 16 r         4     3     4     4  7.95  3.77  4.5   5.90
```

The use of `c(..)` is to de-matrix the results of column-scaling (did you notice that your structure has embedded matrices?).

If you're using `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer, then you can shorten that slightly to just

```r
data %>%
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~ c(scale(.)) * 2 + 5.5, .names = "S_{.col}"),
    .by = V_1
  )
```

Comment: @2ralf just add `.by = V_1` within your mutate call

Comment: I see ... didn't catch that, thank you. Fixed.

Comment: @2ralf check the updated solution

Comment: @onyambu Again, thank you but after updating I have exactly the same values and it is not standardized according to V_1. Do you happen to have the whole code so I can try it?

Comment: @2ralf The answer has been updated. Check it, Try it again. ie you can use `data <- data%>%group_by(V_1)%>%....`

Comment: Thank you all you beautiful people! The solution that works is:                                   
    data %>%
      group_by(V_1) %>% 
      mutate(across(everything(), ~ c(scale(.)) * 2 + 5.5, .names = "S_{.col}"))

Answer (score 1):

Or you to it more complicated with pivoting:
Note: What @r2evans does in 1 line we need 6 lines. :-)

```
library(tdiyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-V_1) %>% 
  mutate(value_S = scale(value)*2 + 5.5, .keep="unused") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value_S, names_prefix = "S_") %>% 
  cbind(df[-1])
```

```
   V_1 id    S_V_2    S_V_3    S_V_4    S_V_5 V_2 V_3 V_4 V_5
1    x  1 3.889283 3.889283 2.014993 3.889283   3   3   2   3
2    x  2 5.763572 5.763572 3.889283 3.889283   4   4   3   3
3    x  3 2.014993 7.637861 5.763572 5.763572   2   5   4   4
4    x  4 7.637861 5.763572 7.637861 5.763572   5   4   5   4
5    t  5 9.512150 2.014993 5.763572 7.637861   6   2   4   5
6    t  6 5.763572 3.889283 7.637861 5.763572   4   3   5   4
7    t  7 7.637861 5.763572 5.763572 7.637861   5   4   4   5
8    t  8 3.889283 7.637861 9.512150 5.763572   3   5   6   4
9    s  9 5.763572 9.512150 2.014993 5.763572   4   6   2   4
10   s 10 2.014993 7.637861 5.763572 5.763572   2   5   4   4
11   s 11 3.889283 5.763572 3.889283 9.512150   3   4   3   6
12   s 12 5.763572 7.637861 5.763572 2.014993   4   5   4   2
13   r 13 3.889283 5.763572 7.637861 2.014993   3   4   5   2
14   r 14 2.014993 3.889283 5.763572 5.763572   2   3   4   4
15   r 15 3.889283 5.763572 5.763572 7.637861   3   4   4   5
16   r 16 5.763572 3.889283 5.763572 5.763572   4   3   4   4
```